# Cannot connect to Ubuntu Desktop from Windows RDP

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, xrdp

I know that a lot of similar questions was asked already, but none of them bring me a solution yet.
What I'm trying to do is connect from Windows 10 RDP to Ubuntu Desktop running on Ubuntu 18.04.2.
On Ubuntu xrdp installed. Ini file of xrdp was modified - Xorg section was commented out, autorun was set to Xvnc (it was commented out by the reason that xrdp session breaking immediately after connection). I did it because of look like Xvnc session was working but after a few seconds, I got an error message.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was fixed by reinstalling `xrdp` and `tightvncserver` and then installation in proper order:

1. `tightvncserver`.
2. `xrdp`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue with **Ubuntu 18.04.2 and xRDP**.  The xorgxrdp package does not get installed on Ubuntu 18.04.2 and this is why you have the problem connecting dialog box showing....

Ubuntu 18.04.2 introduces the xorg-xserver-core-hwe-18.04 package which is not recognized by the xorgxrdp package made available on Ubuntu official repositories
(More info can be found at http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=13390)

**Quick fix to still use xorgxrdp backend component**

To use xRDP and the xorgxrdp backend compoment, you have to either

- perform a custom installation (compile from source - you can use the script located at http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=13432
- Use the unofficial packages prepared by Thiago Martin by issuing the following commands

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:martinx/xrdp-hwe-18.04 -y
  sudo apt-get update
  ```

  or use the script located here to automate the process (http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=13487)

Hope this help
Till next time
See ya